# Howto reduce skype video outgoing traffic?

Tags: linux, video, camera, skype

## Issue background

I'm having having problems with skype under linux. My video calls are all the time non-continuous and they're getting stuck.
The situation is the same whether I use skype alone, or with a preload:
`skype`
`LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib32/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype &`
`LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib32/libv4lconvert.so.0 skype &`

Turning-off (compiz) graphical effects in KDE or switching to LXDE (`openbox-lxde --replace`) doesn't help much.

From `atop` I can see that my outgoing traffic so is around 1500Kbps while incoming is around 150Kbps. When I select `stop my video` the outgoing traffic immediately falls to 70Kbps.

So I suppose that the issue is that skype is sending too large video, which jams the network and results in stuck call. I went thru skype settings and I cannot find anywhere video size settings. I also don't know how to set-up video size in v4l which is underneath skype.

**So how could I make skype sending smaller video?**

## Technical info

> $ cat /etc/debian_version
> wheezy/sid
>
> $ uname -a
> Linux Khedron 3.2.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Sun Feb 5 15:17:15 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
>
> $ skype --version
> Skype 2.2.0.35

```
$ dpkg -l *v4l*
ii  lib32v4l-0              0.8.6-1 
ii  libv4l-0                0.8.6-1 
ii  libv4lconvert0          0.8.6-1 
ii  qv4l2                   0.8.6-1 
ii  v4l-conf                3.102-3 
ii  v4l-utils               0.8.6-1
```

> $ lsusb | grep Chicony
> Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b15e Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd
> The HP webcam is identified as Chicony device.

```
$ lsmod | grep uvcvideo
uvcvideo               57744  0 
videodev               70889  1 uvcvideo
media                  18148  2 uvcvideo,videodev
usbcore               128498  8 
uvcvideo,btusb,usb_storage,usbhid,uas,xhci_hcd,ehci_hcd
```

Comment: Change in /$HOME/.Skype/(YourUserName)/config.xml doesnt seems to be reducing the amount of traffic:  
[webcam video size in Skype](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/236585-50-webcam-video-size-skype-ubuntu)    <br/>
[How to set Skype webcam INPUT size](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=939486)